# A very basic question about particle (leptons, hadrons) interactions

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, strong-force

Suppose a particle reaction $A+B\to C+D$ is allowed in nature. Then, the reactions,
\begin{align}
A&\to \bar{B}+C+D,\\ \bar{C}+\bar{D}&\to \bar{A}+\bar{B},\\ B&\to\bar{A}+C+D,\\& \ldots\text{ etc.}
\end{align}
are also allowed in nature (but maybe they occur at different rates). Can we claim that if $A+B\to C+D$ is governed by strong interactions (or anything else), the others will also be governed by strong interactions?

Comment: 1. What, exactly, do you mean by "governed"? 2. It is certainly not true that all these reactions are "allowed": For one some of these reactions may be trivially forbidden by kinematic constraints.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have been careful. For example, $n\to p+e^-+\bar{\nu}_e$ is governed by weak interactions. If kinematic constraints are satisfied, $e^+ +n\to p+\ne_e$ is also mediated by weak interactions. By governed, I mean, mediated.

Comment: Your title has an alarming  consonant transposition. If allowed kinematically, basically yes. Note the middle reaction you wrote could go backwards, too...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not anymore, it doesn't.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. Do you understand how to draw Feynman diagrams corresponding to the "mediations"? If yes, what specific problem do you have in figuring out the answer here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind What if we don't know the quark structures but know all the quantum numbers such as lepton number, baryon number, strangeness, etc? Can we answer this?

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer (to be updated)**

Let me try my own answer to this question. Let the process $$A+B\to C+D$$ occurs/is allowed in nature. This means that all the quantum numbers, $L, B, Q,...$ are conserved. Let me collectively denote them by $x=(L, B,Q,...)$. Then, $$x_A+x_B=x_C+x_D$$ which also means, trivially, $x_A=x_C+x_D+(-x_B).$, Since the antiparticles carry flipped values of the quantum numbers $x$, if $x$ is conserved in $A+B\to C+D$, it will also be conserved in the reactions
\begin{align}
A&\to \bar{B}+C+D,\\ \bar{C}+\bar{D}&\to \bar{A}+\bar{B},\\ B&\to\bar{A}+C+D,\\& \ldots\text{ etc.}
\end{align}
and hence, they will also be allowed, provided kinematic constraints are satisfied.

In addition, if it is found that strangeness (S), isospin (I), etc are violated in $A+B\to C+D$, then this process must be mediated by weak interactions, and so does the other processes associated with it listed above.

However, if $S, I_3$ all are conserved, but a neutrino is involved, the process is still governed by weak interactions, and if $\gamma$ is involved, the process must be mediated by electromagnetic interactions.

Please feel free to comment on this/correct any error.